# Android Studio - Program type already present: org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers

Tags: android-studio, hamcrest, monkeylearn

I have no idea why this error exists:

```
Program type already present: org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

My code in in the scope if dependency of build.gradle (Module: app) is:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation ('junit:junit:4.12'){
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.monkeylearn:monkeylearn-java:0.1.4'
```

}

MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.monkeylearn.MonkeyLearn;
import com.monkeylearn.MonkeyLearnException;
import com.monkeylearn.MonkeyLearnResponse;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            MonkeyLearn ml = new MonkeyLearn("*******************************");
            String moduleId = "*********";
            String[] textList = {"This is a text to test your classifier", "This is some more text"};
            MonkeyLearnResponse res = ml.classifiers.classify(moduleId, textList, true);
            System.out.println( res.arrayResult );
        } catch (MonkeyLearnException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you seeing this error when you are trying to run tests are run your app?

Comment: This error exists when I try to build the project. Then, it cannot be built successfully.

Comment: Try to comment out the androidTestImplementation and testImplementation dependencies and build your project again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar problem with `simple-json` in another question that I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51551160/2855059).
I suggest you do the same for `monkeylearn-java` and `junit` or any other non-google dependencies one by one, I mean download their jar files and put them in the `libs` folder one by one, to find out which one is the problem, and leave it be in `libs` folder.

I think this is a bug either in Android Studio or in Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with `simple-json`. For that the solution was to exclude the JUnit dependency.

I am not an expert on Android programming but I find it strange that you exclude `hamcrest-core` from the JUnit `testImplementation`. I would rather suggest to exclude transitive dependencies from external libs.

For `simple-json` this was my solution:

```
implementation('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
}
```

Maybe you can do the same for `monkeylearn-java`?