# Program type already present: org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When i build my app, I got follow error.

> Program type already present: org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers
>
> Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

I have google my problem and fond the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49841688/android-studio-program-type-already-present-org-hamcrest-corematchers) , but can't get the proper answer .

This is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            ndk {
                moduleName "exec"
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
    configurations.all{
        resolutionStrategy.force 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.41'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.41'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.10'
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @sanevys  yes ,  My project finish build after i delete this dependency   `implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'`

Comment: Yes if i delete the dependancy it also works. But I need the dependancy :/

Comment: @sanevys  That library  is handle jsonObject ,you  could replace it with some other library  or  use JSONObject that android provide.

Comment: I'm trying to use different lib https://github.com/Ritaja/java-exchange-rates

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Download jar file of `json-simple 1.1.1` and put it in `libs` folder.

And remove `implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'` from `build.gradle`.

I don't know why this solves the problem because I don't know why this problem occurs at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I encountered a similar error saying like that.

I figured out by syncing my app gradle. It turned out that I modified app gradle code and didn't sync but built the project.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that excluding the dependent JUnit from `json-simple` solves this issue as well:

```
implementation('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
}
```

The latest version of `simple-json` depends on JUnit 4.1, which depends on `hamcrest-core:1.1` which in my case conflicted with the existing `hamcrest-core:1.3`.